# Cheking added file to upload python, pylons?

Tags: python, pylons

I try to upload file, how can i check if file is upload

when i send empty input witch file upload i get

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'filename'
```

How can i check added file?

Answer (score 1):

be sure to set multipart=True and to omit method="POST"

```
${h.form(c.formUrl, multipart=True)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question, but [here](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonsdocs/Form+Handling#file-uploads) you have full examples on how to handle file upload on pylons.

Answer (score 0):

```
uploaded_file = request.params['fieldname']
if uploaded_file:
    print uploaded_file.filename
```